# One Object Item insert into Array Mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

**this my structure**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId,//PropertyTrackingModel Object

    "Items": [{
        "Date": "2018-01-29",
        "Tracks": [{
            "ModifiedDate": "2018-06-29T10:21:03.1268154+00:00"
        }]
    }, {
        "Date": "2018-08-29",
        "Tracks": [{
            "ModifiedDate": "2018-08-29T10:21:03.1268154+00:00"
        }]
    }]
}
```

so i want insert New Tracks in date=="2018-08-29" collection 
and it like daily data

finaly  i need

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId,//PropertyTrackingModel Object
        "Items": [{
            "Date": "2018-01-29",
            "Tracks": [{
                "ModifiedDate": "2018-06-29T10:21:03.1268154+00:00"
            }]
        }, {
            "Date": "2018-08-29",
            "Tracks": [{
                "ModifiedDate": "2018-08-29T10:21:03.1268154+00:00"
            },
           {
                "ModifiedDate": "2018-08-29T10:21:03.1268154+00:00"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

thank all of you 
bast way using C# mongo driver function

Comment: Can you please remove all the redundant fields? Please give the most basic and complete example of the code.

Comment: edit done ,so could you give me some Pointers,thanks